# Javascript Help: Clicking an element affects that element AND other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I haven't really got experience using javascript, so I'm currently trying out the basic first steps of getting the hang of it.

---

### The setup:

I've got [these four div boxes in parent-container with the flex-property](https://codepen.io/MikaTheDesigner/pen/oNEdrrq), each box with 25% width.

```
<section>
    <div class="box box1"></div>

    <div class="box box2"></div>

    <div class="box box3"></div>

    <div class="box box4"></div>
</section>
```

When **hovering** over one of the boxes, that particular box gets 40% in width, and the remaining boxes gets reduced to 20%.

When you then **click** one of the boxes, that box gets 85% width, and the remaining boxes gets reduced to 5%.

**If** you then **click** another box, **that** box gets 85% width, and remaining boxes gets reduced to 5%.

To get back to the all-25%-width-boxes, using a simple cross will do the job (haven't coded this yet, though).

---

### Problem/Troubleshooting:

I started off by trying to do an all-CSS solution using input checkboxes, but quickly realized this would not work, as CSS do not have a selector that can have effect on previous siblings.

Therefore, **I need two javascript functions.**

(1) When clicking one of the boxes, that element gets a certain width, as well as the remaining boxes getting a smaller width.

(2) If you have already clicked one of the boxes, which now is 85% width, if you click one of the other boxes, **that** particular box is now "the selected one", and will be 85% in width.

I have a feeling it's two simple functions. I just do not have experience using javascript, so I'm uncertain of what to write.

Comment: you should start by reading on Javascript. Start from the basics and try it yourself and at that point, come back and ask your question giving evidence that you actually tried something before asking

Comment: You don't have to affect previous siblings specifically. You can simply give all the boxes `flex: 1` by default and override the selected one with `flex: 0 0 85%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said CherryDT it can be done by `flex-basis`

Or if can be done with css e.g. radio group and checked

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

input {
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
.box2 {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2)
}
.box3 {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}
.box4 {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4)
}

input:checked + section:hover input {
  width: 20%;
}

input:checked + section:hover input:hover {
  width: 40%;
}

input:not(:checked) + section input {
  width: 5%;
}

input:not(:checked) + section input:checked {
  width: 85%;
}

input:checked + section > label {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<input id="hidden" hidden type="radio" name="group"  class="box1" value="0" checked />
<section>
    <label for="hidden">
      X
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="group"  class="box1" value="1"/>
    <input type="radio" name="group" class="box2" value="2"/>
    <input type="radio" name="group" class="box3" value="3"/>
    <input type="radio" name="group"class="box4" value="4"/>
</section>
```

Comment: Love this solution, it behaves as described in question, but if you use radio inputs, it complicates the matter of for example image being displayed in these rectangles, does'nt it?

Comment: Absolutely stunning solutions, @Sergey and @CherryDT! That was exactly what I tried at first myself, using radio checkboxes inside of div's, but did not think of flex-basis.

I imagine you could use background images for the inputs, instead of background colors.
But what about other content such as text? I was using div's because I know I wanted to but text inside each of the boxes. But you can't put text inside an input, right?

Comment: Background images will work
https://codepen.io/isergey87/pen/yLvEYQN

Comment: For render any content `input+label` can be used
a bit simplified using flex-basis
https://codepen.io/isergey87/pen/MWQXKge

Comment: Appreciate your help, @Sergey. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using jQuery:

```js
$(".box").on({ 
    mouseenter: function(){
        if ($(".box.clicked").length) return false;

        $(this).siblings(".box").css("width","20%");
        $(this).css("width","40%");
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        if ($(".box.clicked").length) return false;

        $(this).siblings(".box").css("width","25%");
        $(this).css("width","25%");
    }
})

$(".box").on("click", function(e){

    $(".box.clicked").css("width","5%");
    $(".box.clicked").removeClass("clicked");

    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    $(this).css("width","85%");
    $(this).siblings(".box").css("width","5%");

    if ($(e.target).hasClass("exit")) {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
        $(this).css("width","25%");
        $(this).siblings(".box").css("width","25%");
    }
    
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 250px;
}
.box {
    width: 25%;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
.box1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.box2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.box3 {
    background-color: green;
}
.box4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.box .exit {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.box.clicked .exit {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<section>
    <div class="box box1">
        <p class="exit">×</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box box2">
        <p class="exit">×</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box box3">
        <p class="exit">×</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box box4">
        <p class="exit">×</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

You could also asssign those properties to classes and then just add/remove classes on the events, but structure will be overall the same.

Next time, please try to code yourself first and provide examples of what you've tried.

Comment: I did try coding it.
Started off using input checkboxes, as wrote in my post. Thereafter, I tried a basic "if else" javascript function, but didn't get it to finish it, because of my lack of experience with javascript.